# integration of C/C++ unit test with maven

Tags: c, maven

We are planning to integrate our native c/c++ projects into a maven build process as we are porting the code for Android. Further we want to formulate unit tests that are run automatically using the standard maven syntax (as for java unit tests) also for the c/c++ projects which are currently using CUnit. Is this possible to integrate it with maven ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a direct way to do this but I'd do the following:

1. Create a configurable shell/batch script that is responsible for executing the unit tests.
2. Integrate the execution of this script into maven by binding the script to test phase via the [exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

This setup would run your C++ unit tests every time when the [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) is started, eg. by running: `mvn test`.

Alternatively you can do the same with an [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) script and the [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Here is an example (an altered version from the Exec plugin usage page):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>run-cpp-tests.sh</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Comment: Sorry i am very new to android and Maven so one question, I will convert my C/C++ code using jni , then in android prj will be doing something like  System.loadLibrary("abc");In this case how shell script will fit in.

Comment: Apparently I missed the point with my reply :) Run your unit tests against your java code with JUnit (or your preferred Java unit testing framework) from Maven and run those against the C++ code with CUnit from the script.

Comment: I wouldn't consider running C++ tests from Java (like JUnit or TestNG) a good idea by the very nature of unit tests and vica versa.