# 'maven test' is only for Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, lifecycle, maven-surefire-plugin

I am developing in not common language (IBM SQL PL) and I want to integrate the unit system framework of that language into the lifecycle of Maven.

I would like to know how the command `maven test` works. It seems that the normal execution is only for Java, because the three [SurefireProviders](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/api.html) are jUnit3, jUnit4 and TestNG. The SurefireProvider documentation does not explain nor gives indications about other providers for different programming languages.

I can also configure the execution of my programming language tests into the test phase, but I do not know the side effects. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19356216/456274

In conclusion, what is the best way to integrate unit test report into `maven test` execution and be part of the lifecycle to include that into a continuous integration?

Answer (score 2):

There are similar and more common issues for developers who want to test their javascript code with maven.

You should write your own maven plugin which integrates your unit testing framework to maven lifecycle: http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

A good example is the Jasmine Maven Plugin which integrate jasmine, a unit testing framework for javascript: http://searls.github.io/jasmine-maven-plugin/

Then, by adding your custom maven plugin in test goal, your "mvn test" command will invoke it.